# Arrays Start at \$\pi\$

Tags: code-golf, array

Your task is to take an array of numbers and a real number and return the value at that point in the array. Arrays start at \$\pi\$ and are counted in \$\pi\$ intervals. Thing is, we're actually going to interpolate between elements given the "index". As an example:

```
Index:    1π   2π   3π   4π   5π   6π
Array: [ 1.1, 1.3, 6.9, 4.2, 1.3, 3.7 ]
```

Because it's \$\pi\$, we have to do the obligatory trigonometry, so we'll be using cosine interpolation using the following formula:

\${\cos(i \mod \pi) + 1 \over 2} * (\alpha - \beta) + \beta\$

where:

- \$i\$ is the input "index"
- \$\alpha\$ is the value of the element immediately before the "index"
- \$\beta\$ is the value of the element immediately after the "index"
- \$\cos\$ takes its angle in radians

## Example

Given [1.3, 3.7, 6.9], 5.3:

Index 5.3 is between \$1\pi\$ and \$2\pi\$, so 1.3 will be used for `before` and 3.7 will be used for `after`. Putting it into the formula, we get:

\${\cos(5.3 \mod \pi) + 1 \over 2} * (1.3 - 3.7) + 3.7\$

Which comes out to 3.165

## Notes

- Input and output may be in any convenient format
- You may assume the input number is greater than \$\pi\$ and less than `array length` * \$\pi\$
- You may assume the input array will be at least 2 elements long.
- Your result must have at least two decimal points of precision, be accurate to within 0.05, and support numbers up to 100 for this precision/accuracy. (single-precision floats are more than sufficient to meet this requirement)

Happy Golfing!

Comment: FYI golfers, it might be shorter to write rewrite \$(\cos(x)+1)/2\$ as \$\cos(x/2)^2\$ using the [half-angle formula](http://www.softschools.com/math/trigonometry/half_angle_formulas/) for \$\cos\$.

Comment: Can I take in a dictionary with doubles as its keys? The doubles will be whole numbers, of course.

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance, sure. I doubt that's going to help you, but that's a perfectly reasonable representation of arrays since that's how Lua does it.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I don't see why that would matter. 3.7 is between pi and 2pi.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>59</s> 53 bytes

```r
function(x,i)x[0:1+i%/%pi]%*%c(a<-cos(i%%pi/2)^2,1-a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCJ1OzItrAylA7U1VftSAzVlVLNVkj0UY3Ob9YI1MVKKJvpBlnpGOom6j5P00jWcNQz1jHWM9cx0zPUlPHVM9Y8z8A)

Nothing too clever here - just an R version of the formula in the question. 
Thanks @MickyT for saving a byte, and to @Giueseppe and indirectly @xnor for another two, and thanks to @RobinRyder for saving a further 3.

Comment: I think you can drop a byte with `...*(cos(i%%pi)+1)/2`

Comment: @MickyT thanks, I had originally put the +1 in the parentheses, but had added a redundant pair of parentheses so ending up with 60 bytes

Comment: [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCJ1NTo9K2ItrAylA7U1VftSAzVjPaKFY3JTMtTaNSUys5v1gjUxUorG@kGWf0P00jWcNQz1jHWM9cx0zPUlPHVM9Y8z8A) following xnor's comment about the half-angle formula.

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCJ1OzItrAylA7U1VftSAzVlVLNVkj0UY3Ob9YI1MVKKJvpBlnpGOom6j5P00jWcNQz1jHWM9cx0zPUlPHVM9Y8z8A "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>85</s> 74 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to @xnor
-2 bytes thanks to @Quintec

This takes advantage of the Python 3.8 pre-release's new `:=` assignment operator. Other than that, this is really just the equation written out in Python.

```python
import math
lambda l,i:cos(i%math.pi/2)**2*(l[(j:=int(i/pi))-1]-l[j])+l[j]
```

Usage:

```python
>>> p=lambda l,i:cos(i%math.pi/2)**2*(l[(j:=int(i/pi))-1]-l[j])+l[j]
>>> print(p([1.3, 3.7, 6.9],5.3))
3.165249203414993
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pYw5DsMgEAB7v4ImEkvwWjbKYUt@CaIgSeG1wKwIjV9PxBvSTDEjDZ9lS4d5cq6VIqdcRPRl64KPr48XQdPyTl9Jl2aRaZhAqUnJYOW@rHQUSQMTQD@6PtjdwbWx8vrfoOPcEks7otHC4EOLO85O39AA1B8)

Comment: You can just [assign `j` the first place it's mentioned](https://tio.run/##FclNDsIgEEDhvaeYjclMS2mQ@NekJyEsUGM6DZQJsvH0aDdv8T351iVv9ialtXfJCVKoC3CSXGp3kDmG9HgFiIonfOYP8lGYekPjqcPocJ1m3iry@FcajB@iWz31e5uUfQk6o60Cq68KLvru1VlbovYD) -- part of the power of assignment expressions is that they evaluate to the value as well as assigning it.

Comment: Another byte save: Use trig identities to convert `(cos(i%pi)+1)/2`  to `cos(i%pi/2)**2`

Comment: @xnor Good point. I knew I was using that wrong

Comment: @xnor I don't understand the trig identity magic, but I appreciate the tip. Updating answer

Comment: You can drop the `p=` since anonymous functions are ok

Comment: @Quintec Thanks. Answer updated

Comment: Forgot to update bytecount :)

Comment: Whoops, thanks. Fixed

Comment: Now Python beat me :(

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
d©ØPṪÆẠ‘H×I_@Ḋ}®ị
```

A full program accepting \$i\$ and the array which prints the interpolated value.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT0Awv9qZWxsef//ZMKpw5hQ4bmqw4bhuqDigJhIw5dJX0DhuIp9wq7hu4v///81LjP/WzEuMywgMy43LCA2Ljld)**

#### How?

Interpolates between all neighbours using \$\frac{\cos(i \mod \pi)+1}2\$ then picks the relevant value.

```
d©ØPṪÆẠ‘H×I_@Ḋ}®ị - Link: number, i; list of numbers, A
  ØP              - pi (ish) = 3.141592653589793
d                 - divmod = [i//pi, i%pi]
 ©                - (copy to register for later)
    Ṫ             - tail (gets i%pi leaving register copy as [i//pi])  
     ÆẠ           - cosine = cos(i%pi)
       ‘          - increment
        H         - halve
         ×        - multiply by A (vectorises)
          I       - increments -- i.e. (cos(i%pi)+1)(r-l)/2 for neighbours [l,r]
             Ḋ}   - dequeue A
           _@     - swapped arg subtract (vectorises) -- i.e. r-(cos(i%pi)+1)(r-l)/2
                  -                                         = r+(cos(i%pi)+1)(l-r)/2
               ®  - recall value from the register
                ị - index into (vectorises) -- i.e. [β+(cos(i%pi)+1)(α-β)/2]
                  - implicit print of Jelly representation (only 1 entry so [] wont appear)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 69 bytes

```cs
n=>m=>(Math.Cos(m%Math.PI)+1)/2*(n[m=(int)(m/Math.PI)-1]-n[++m])+n[m]
```

<s>I beat Python!</s> <s>Darn it, Python beat me.</s> I beat Python again!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYm9CsIwEIB3n6KLcGfSlFpUpCaLIAgKbg4hQxtTDJgr2BYR8dmjWNy@H9ultvNxN5DdXNqhvjlt@GhPqoK3fKxKNTKSVEEqOFb9VWzbDsL0h6c9shyz@QxIBwmeeoSQ/Veam5Q0Y8Eg@34Ty8n57nt38OSgAXIPbV65KHhSiBVPlmL9RliIArGMHw)

Comment: Look on the bright side. Neither of us stood a chance against Jelly

Comment: @senox13 Except maybe Stax

Answer (score 2):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 51 bytes

```
f a,i{j=i//PI;[(cos(i%PI)+1)/2*(a[j-1]-a[j])+a[j]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfz/P00hUSezOss2U18/wNM6WiM5v1gjUzXAU1PbUFPfSEsjMTpL1zBWF0jFamqDyNja/7mJmXnVXJxpGtGGesY6CsZ65joKZnqWsToKpnrGmly1/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>47</s> <s>46</s> 38 bytes

```
u0;J=V/MP[A=UgJc) nUgJf))½McVuMP)Ä]×+A
```

To be continued... (golfing)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/v9TA2ss2TN83INrRNjTdK1lTIQ9IpWlqHtrrmxxW6hugebgl9vB0bcf//6MN9Yx1FIz1zHUUzPQsY7lM9YwB)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, <s>39</s> 37 bytes

2 bytes saved thanks to Adám

```
2⊃m+(-/m←⎕[0 1+⌊n÷○1])÷2÷1+2○(○1)|n←⎕
```

[Try it online!Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4bPepqztXW0NXPBYoB5aINFAy1H/V05R3e/mh6t2Gs5uHtRoe3G2obAXkaIBHNmjyIyv9A/f/TuEz1jLkM9YwVjPXMFcz0LAE)

Explanation:

```
n←⎕ prompt for input of integer

2÷1+2○(○1)|n evaluate first term of formula

[0 1+⌊n÷○1] identify indices of alpha and beta

m←⎕[...] prompt for input of vector and select alpha and beta

-/m alpha-beta

2⊃m+ take result of adding beta to complete the equation
```

Comment: [`×.5×` → `÷2÷` and `m[2]` → `2⊃m`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4bPepqztXW0NXPBYoB5aINFAy1H/V05R3e/mh6t2Gs5uHtRoe3G2obAXkaIBHNmjyIyv9A/f/TuEz1jLkM9YwVjPXMFcz0LAE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
≈ëBü☺ÆssÅ¢â)KjjïΔ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=f7894281019273738f9b83294b6a6a8bff&i=[1.3,+3.7,+6.9],+5.3&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented it looks like this.

```
VP|%    divmod with pi;  push div and mod results separately
|7^h    do (cos(modpart) + 1) / 2
sX      swap the original div result to top of stack, store it in the x register
v       decrement
;:-     pairwise differences of array
@       get element at index
N*      negate and multiply
;x@     get element from the original array at the x index, where x is the register
+       add
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=VP%7C%25%09divmod+with+pi%3B++push+div+and+mod+results+separately%0A%7C7%5Eh%09do+%28cos%28modpart%29+%2B+1%29+%2F+2%0AsX++%09swap+the+original+div+result+to+top+of+stack,+store+it+in+the+x+register%0Av+++%09decrement%0A%3B%3A-+%09pairwise+differences+of+array%0A%40+++%09get+element+at+index%0AN*++%09negate+and+multiply%0A%3Bx%40+%09get+element+from+the+original+array+at+the+x+index,+where+x+is+the+register%0A%2B+++%09add&i=[1.3,+3.7,+6.9],+5.3&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 65 bytes

```hs
v!i|(c,r)<-properFraction$i/pi=cos(r*pi/2)^2*(v!!(c-1)-v!!c)+v!!c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZBCoMwEADAr2zAQ2KTiIYqhXrtJ8RCWIQu1WRZxVP/nraXYV5xfy/rWsqp6KPRirk7lsyLPCTiQTlV1DCNmHctNVPTmWdX61Mpja417hc0l79li5RgBBZKB1QwtT5YCH6w0PvbDAquPpQv)

Note: the array is represented as a list.

Thanks to @xnor for the half-angle tip.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 67 bytes

```ruby
->a,i{z=Math::PI;Math.cos(i%z/2)**2*(a[-1+j=(i/z).to_i]-a[j])+a[j]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cuUSezusrWN7Ekw8oqwNMaxNBLzi/WyFSt0jfS1NIy0tJIjNY11M6y1cjUr9LUK8mPz4zVTYzOitXUBpG1/wsU0qKjDfWMdYz1zHXM9CxjdRRM9Yxj/wMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>23</s> <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
³%ØPÆẠ×_++H
÷ØPịÇ/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QZtXDMwIOtz3cteDw9HhtbQ@uw9uBAg93dx9u1////7@pnvH/aEM9Yx1jPXMdMz3LWAA)

```
÷ØPịṁØ½µ³%ØPÆẠ×I_@SH    Dyadic link, arguments x (index) and Z (array):
÷ØP                     x/pi
   ị                    Index (into Z).
                        When x/pi is an integer, returns that elt of Z.
                        Otherwise returns 2 elements at floor and ceiling.
     Ø½                   [1,2] (generic 2 element array)
    ṁØ½                 Mold; shape like [1,2] to ensure we have 2 elements.
       µ                Start a new, monadic chain with the result [a,b]
        ³%ØPÆẠ×I_@SH    Monadic chain
        ³               x
         %ØP            x mod pi
            ÆẠ          Unarccosine; cos(x mod pi).
               I          Increment; b-a.
              ×I        (b-a) cos(x mod pi)
                  S       a+b
                _@S     a + b - (b-a) cos(x mod pi)
                   H    Halve; this is equivalent to our desired result.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>22</s> <s>21</s> <s>20</s> 19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žq‰`Å¾>;UÝèÐÁ-θX*-θ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7CRw0bEg63HtpnZx16eO7hFYcnHG7UPbcjQgtI/P9vqmfMFW2oZ6xjrGeuY6ZnGQsA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/k5ulir6SQmJeioGQPZj5qmwRkFv8/uq/wUcOGhMOth/bZWYcennt4xeEJhxt1z@2I0AIS/3X@m@oZc0Ub6hnrKBjrmesomOlZxnIZGumZgQQNdRTAMkBBHQUTPSMoF6zQQs8kFgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
žq‰        # Take the divmod PI of the (implicit) input-decimal
           # (part = input integer-divided by PI, remainder = input modulo-PI)
           #  i.e. 5.3 → [1, 2.158...]
   `       # Push both values separately to the stack
    Å¾     # Take the cosine of the remainder
           #  i.e. 2.158... → -0.554...
      >    # Increase it by 1
           #  i.e. -0.554... → 0.554...
       ;   # Halve it
           #  i.e. 0.554... → 0.222...
        U  # Pop and store it in variable `X`
    Ý      # Pop the part, and push a list in the range [0, part]
           #  i.e. 1 → [0, 1]
     è     # (0-based) index all of them into the (implicit) input-list
           #   i.e. [1.3, 3.7, 6.9] and [0, 1] → [1.3, 3.7]
Ð          # Triplicate this list
 Á         # Rotate the last copy once towards the right
           #  i.e. [1.3, 3.7] → [3.7, 1.3]
  -        # Subtract the values in the top two lists from one another
           #  i.e. [1.3, 3.7] and [3.7, 1.3] → [-2.4, 2.4]
   θ       # Pop and only leave the last value of this list
           #  i.e. [-2.4, 2.4] → 2.4
    X*     # Multiply it by `X`
           #  i.e. 2.4 * `X`=0.222... → 0.534...
     -     # Subtract it from each of the values in the list we triplicated
           #  i.e. [1.3, 3.7] - 0.534... → [0.765..., 3.165...]
      θ    # And only leave the last value of this list
           #  i.e. [0.765..., 3.165...] → 3.165...
           # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## C (GCC) <s>99</s> 79 bytes

-20 bytes ceilingcat

```
float P=3.141593;b;
#define f(i,a)(cos(fmod(i,P))+1)/2*(a[b=i/P-1]-a[++b])+a[b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3LCoMwFET3fsWlpZA0D0lTWyT4D@5tFtdoJOCjVHfirzcNdDlnDjNODM7F6McFN6grLdVdFaU2rcnOXe/D3IMngSMlblmJn5YupZpSpmh@uxJs2irktVBWYMNYaylLyMYwbzBhmAmFPQP4z2OjLVSwK6m5lk/@kOVhUvv@JN2T08W/5hNPf0USkFKTHfHr/IjDGsU4/QA)

Calling code

```
int main() {
  float a[3] = {1.3,3.7,6.9};
  printf("%f\n", f(5.3,a));
}
```

note that it needed the compiler flag `-lm` to link with math libraries, so +3 bytes if you count that.

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 54 bytes

```
${Cos[y%PI/2]^2*&`-@(j:=x[1'-1*Floor[y'-y/PI]-1])+j@1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcHBCoIwGADgu0@xg2nZNpmjIkEQhMBLeOj280fDZiXRxO3QiJ599X3KOdXfdRhIWYX40xgLftG1eYHnIksurF6OZfUGkTKRHZ7GzOBT5vOuRSZwtR5r8Q1Hra8W4mnqbxh18@PlTtq6RlltIRkogYj8AQguKZF8R8mW75GSDZcYIYYf)

### Explanation

```
${Cos[y%PI/2]^2*&`-@(j:=x[1'-1*Floor[y'-y/PI]-1])+j@1}
${                                                   }  parameters: x, y
  Cos[y%PI/2]^2                                         the scaling function factor
               *                                        times
                     j:=                                set j to
                        x[                     ]        the element in x at
                          1'-1*Floor[y'-y/PI]-1         the closest indices scaled by PI
                &`-@(                           )       spread subtraction over bounds
                                                 +j@1   add the upper bound
```